# Setting Minutes in Calendar differs depending on TimeZone

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

I just found a strange behavior with the JAVA Calendar Class. 
When I set the minutes to 0 the result differs depending on the used TimeZone.

Does anyone know why?

**Example Code**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class CalendarTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Timestamp(1477780200000L);
        System.out.println(date); // 2016-10-30 00:30:00.0

        testMethod(date, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"))); // Sun Oct 30 02:00:00 CET 2016
        testMethod(date, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"))); // Sun Oct 30 02:00:00 CEST 2016
    }

    private static void testMethod(Date date, Calendar c) {
        c.setTime(date);
        c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);

        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

        System.out.println(c.getTime());
    }
}
```

edit (to make my question more understandable):
**changed testMethod**
this changed Method calculates in BOTH(!) cases 
 *Sun Oct 30 02:30:00 CEST 2016*.

```
private static void testMethod(Date date, Calendar c) {
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);

    System.out.println(c.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see in the example code below that displayed date is rather different than real time (in milliseconds). The problem is that Sun Oct 30 02:00:00 `CET` 2016 exists both in `CET` and `CEST` time zone. When switching `CEST` => `CET` you are going back one hour (producing hour overlap). For `Calendar` object, this is very tricky because you are expressing time change in the selected time zone. When you want to reset minutes in this very specific, `Calendar` have to discover in which time zone you are expressing the change.

I'm not 100% how `Calendar` is handling this but in first example `CET`, you specifically suggesting that you want to use `CET`. Therefore, when overlapping takes place `Calendar` can select your suggestion (`CET`). When you are using `GMT` to express it then `Calendar` have to pick one of the time zones `CET` or `CEST` and is selecting `CEST`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Timestamp(1477780200000L);
    System.out.println(date); // 2016-10-30 00:30:00.0
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
    calendar.setTime(date);
    print(1, calendar); // 1: Sun Oct 30 00:30:00 CEST 2016 | 1477780200000
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
    print(2, calendar); // 2: Sun Oct 30 02:30:00 CEST 2016 | 1477787400000
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // minutes expressed in CET
    print(3, calendar); // 3: Sun Oct 30 02:00:00 CET 2016 | 1477789200000

    System.out.println("--");

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
    calendar.setTime(date);
    print(4, calendar); // 4: Sun Oct 30 00:30:00 CEST 2016 | 1477780200000
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
    print(5, calendar); // 5: Sun Oct 30 02:30:00 CEST 2016 | 1477787400000
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // minutes expressed in CET
    print(6, calendar); // 6: Sun Oct 30 02:00:00 CET 2016 | 1477789200000

    System.out.println("--");

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
    calendar.setTime(date);
    print(4, calendar); // 4: Sun Oct 30 00:30:00 CEST 2016 | 1477780200000
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
    print(5, calendar); // 5: Sun Oct 30 02:30:00 CEST 2016 | 1477787400000
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // minutes expressed in GMT
    print(6, calendar); // 6: Sun Oct 30 02:00:00 CEST 2016 | 1477785600000
}

private static void print(int prefix, Calendar calendar) {
    System.out.println(prefix + ": " + calendar.getTime() + " | " + calendar.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

#### Update

What is more interesting is the `Calendar` method `getTimeInMillis`:

```
public long getTimeInMillis() {
    if (!isTimeSet) {
        updateTime();
    }
    return time;
}
```

As you can see time is updated when you are getting it! There is a flag `isTimeSet` which is set to `false` every time you use `set` method like `calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)`. It means that your time becomes *invalid* in terms of right timezone/epoch etc. This method just sets the given calendar field to the given value and that's it. Moreover, this method is not doing any additional checks if your setting is valid. `add` method, on the other hand, respects calendar rules and move your date gracefully.

To summarize. You are setting minutes to 0 which forces calendar to recalculate date. You were right, the `set` is the problematic one.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I still doesn't get why the setting of the minutes causes different results. I mean I set the minutes to 0, so I expect the same hour, but with 0 minutes than before the call of the setter.
 
And I don't get, why the result is shift by 1 hour (from CET to CEST)